# How to reference multiple foreign key to one table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a data warehouse and I decided to use some field in more than one table to increase the speed!

But I have a problem: **How can I reference more than one foreign key to one table in SQL?**

For example: if I have a table for *calendar* like this:

```
calendar(c_id, year, month, day)
```

and another table for *daily snapshots* like this:

```
snapshot(id, c_id, year, ...)
```

How can I reference both *'c_id'* and *'year'* from snapshot to calendar table?

Thank you.

Comment: Which DBMS you are using ?

Comment: It is possible to refer more than one column when the parent table has composite primary key at least in `Sql Server`

Comment: I use microsoft sql server. Is it possible to do this in microsoft sql server??

Comment: What is the primary key of calendar table ?

Comment: 'd_id'. It is just separate rows. like: 1, 2, 3 ...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE calendar ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_calendar_c_id_year UNIQUE (c_id, year)

ALTER TABLE snapshot ADD CONSTRAINT FK_snapshot_c_id_year 
    FOREIGN KEY (c_id, year) REFERENCES calendar (c_id, YEAR)
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess, have to do that!